# Getting different response for same request b/w php and python

Tags: python, php, web-scraping, python-requests, youtube

This is my first question on Stack Overflow. Someone, please help me as I am struggling to find an answer for the past 24 hours.

I tried sending a normal get request to a URL with postman and python. Both returned the same response. But when I tried sending the same get request from a PHP file, it is returning a different response, which is not intended. But all are simple get requests. I want the request made from the PHP file to return the same response as sending a request from postman or python.

Here is the code for both python and PHP.

**Python:**

```
url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q2A5igb7pmA"
response = requests.request("GET", url)
print(response.text)
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
$url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q2A5igb7pmA"; 
$text = file_get_contents($url); 
echo $text;
?>
```

I am trying to build a simple YouTube scraper. Though both the responses look almost similar, if you check out the object **ytInitialPlayerResponse** in their responses, you can find the difference in
`ytInitialPlayerResponse["streamingData"]["formats"][0]["url"]`

Here is a sample response from Python request:

```
<<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ..... >
...
//Same html body
...
<script ...>
var ytInitialPlayerResponse = { 
    "responseContext":{...}, 
    "streamingData":{
        ...,
        "formats":[
            {...,
             "url":"https://rr1---sn-h5576nsr.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=...",
             ...},
             ...
          ],
        ...
     }
};
</script>
```

Here is a sample response from PHP request:

```
<<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ..... >
...
//Same html body
...
<script ...>
var ytInitialPlayerResponse = { 
    "responseContext":{...}, 
    "streamingData":{
        ...,
        "formats":[
            {...,
             "url":"https://rr5---sn-gwpa-qxael.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=...",
             ...},
             ...
          ],
        ...
     }
};
</script>
```

Both responses are almost similar, except for the fact that, the data of the **urls** varies, as you can see from above samples.

**It is working perfectly in localhost, but not when hosted.**

PS: **I also tried adding headers like user-agent, curl request, storing cookies, but nothing seem to work**. The PHP file is hosted in Hostinger.

Comment: what does it return in Python and in PHP ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Gugu72 Both returns the same file, but the data is different. PHP file has different URLs which isn't working. But Python and Postman receives same response with same urls which is working perfectly.

Comment: @brombeer what I want is, the php code should return same response as python, with the same data. Currently php code returns different data than python.

Comment: please provide an example of the differences between the data

Comment: Hi @VishnuThulasidoss, to help you with this question we will need more details: 1. Show us the returned results (both php and python). 2. Show us the user-agents / curl request / cookies used in your request header (if possible without leaking informations) 3. Have you tried running both scripts in local on the same environnement? I believe your PHP is hosted on a server and your python is ran in local?

Comment: I have added sample responses from both. @Gugu72

Comment: I hope now its clear as I have added sample responses. @brombeer

Comment: @XceeD I have added the responses from both. I used the same code as mentioned in the question. It's just plain get request without a user agent. However, I also tried adding different user agents, but it still returning the same response.

Comment: @XceeD also, I just tried in local host, it is working perfectly! The problem is with the hosting it seems.

Comment: Are you hosting both PHP and Python script on Hostinger? And both return something different? Does the URL really matter, does it serve different videos? Could be CDN-thing

Comment: @brombeer I can't host python script on shared hosting, so I'm not sure about that. I think the same.